# Office 365 Calendar API - Filtering Events by Date in C# Client Libraries

Tags: c#, linq, outlook, office365, office365api

In Client Libraries you can apply LINQ filtering on calendar event request:

```
var events = await (from i in Client.Me.Events where i.Subject == "Desired Event Name" select i)
    .Take(50)
    .ExecuteAsync();
```

Or one can use *Where* method, however for *Start* and *End* fields when we want events from specific time period filtering cannot be used as the *DateTime*s are stored as strings. Invocation of *DateTime.Parse* method causes an exception.
This is definitely supposed to be achievable, I even think it was possible at some point and can be done with REST. The begin/finish property is indexed according to documentation. Of course the results can be filtered once received but in that case I started getting events four years old. It really takes a lot of time to get through all the pages in the *IPagedCollection* in this approach. Fortunately though the events appear to be ordered by date, so you can stop the acquisition of new pages once events begin after your period of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Office 365 REST API you were initializing the OutLookServicesClient? I can filter the events use the v1.0 API. You can refer the code below to use the LINQ to filter the with start and end property:

```
   OutlookServicesClient client = new OutlookServicesClient(new Uri("https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0/"), () =>
        {
            return Task.Delay(10).ContinueWith(t => accessToken);
        });



        var events = await (from i in client.Me.Events where (i.Start > DateTimeOffset.Parse("2016-07-18") && i.End< DateTimeOffset.Parse("2016-07-25")) select i)
                        .Take(50)
                        .ExecuteAsync();

        foreach (var appointment in events.CurrentPage)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{appointment.Subject}:\t{appointment.Start}~{appointment.End}");
        }
```

### Update(V2.0)

Install the V2.0 manage assembly `Install-Package Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices-V2.0`

Code:

```
  OutlookServicesClient client = new OutlookServicesClient(new Uri("https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/"), () =>
        {
            return Task.Delay(10).ContinueWith(t => accessToken);
        });

        var events = await (from i in client.Me.Events where (i.Start.DateTime.CompareTo("2016-07-18")>0 && i.End.DateTime.CompareTo("2016-07-25")<0) select i)
                  .Take(50)
                  .ExecuteAsync();

        foreach (var appointment in events.CurrentPage)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{appointment.Subject}:\t{appointment.Start}~{appointment.End}");
        }
```

Comment: I was using 2.0, it seems as if they changed the type of end/start property, as your code produces compile-time error in 2.0. You probably need to use 1.0 to do this.

Comment: Yes, the sample above use the 1.0. I will update the 2.0 manage API sample in my post

Answer (score 0):

Me. I still did not find solution to querying events with LINQ. To view a specified interval one can use
 `Client.Me.CalendarView(from as DateTimeOffset, to as DateTimeOffset)` or `Client.Me.Calendars["<valid calendar id>"].CalendarView(from, to)`. Filtering by function is probably exclusive to client-side code.